# How To Open a New Window using jquery.min.js and calling app.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

A friend gave me this code to apply to my pre-sale page.  It's using Facebook Pixels. The only issue is this code will open the product page in my current window and not in a new window.

this is my app.js file

```
$(".landerclick1").bind({
    click: function () {
        console.log("FB Tracking Start!");
        fbq('trackCustom', "water", {
           category: 'Purchase',
           value: 'landerclick1',
           value: 'landerclick2',
           eventname: 'purchase'
        });
        console.log("FB Tracking Ends!");

        console.log("Other Tracking Start!");
        $('<img src="http://image-pixel-URL-here">').appendTo('.tracker-div');
        console.log("Other Tracking End!");

        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Redirecting...");
            window.location.href = "http://track.stackfasttracking.com/click/1";
        }, 500);
    }
});

$(".landerclick2").bind({
    click: function () {
        var itemId = $(this).attr('item-id');
        console.log("Tracking Item ID: ", itemId);
        console.log("FB Tracking Start!");
        fbq('trackCustom', "water", {
           category: 'Purchase',
           value: 'landerclick1',
           value: 'landerclick2',
           eventname: 'purchase'
        });
        console.log("FB Tracking Ends!");

        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Redirecting...");
            window.location.href = "http://track.stackfasttracking.com/click/2";
        }, 500);
    }
});

$(".track-this").bind({
    click: function () {
        var itemId = $(this).attr('item-id');
        console.log("Tracking Item ID: ", itemId);
        console.log("FB Tracking Start!");
        fbq('trackCustom', "water", {
           category: 'Purchase',
           value: 'landerclick1',
           value: 'landerclick2',
           eventname: 'purchase'
        });
        console.log("FB Tracking Ends!");

        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Redirecting...");
            window.location.href = "http://track.2stack-track.com/click";
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

and this is my a href link that leads to my product page

a href="javascript:void(0);" class="landerclick1"

Comment: Have you tried adding `target="_blank"` to your `a` link?

Comment: no offense, but if you can't open a new window with javascript, you should hire a developer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
        window.location.href = "http://track.stackfasttracking.com/click/2";
```

Use

```
        window.open("http://track.stackfasttracking.com/click/2","_blank");
```

Comment: just tried that, Nothing happens.  I've already tested window.open